# What C++ data structure can handle 'insert' similar to a Java ArrayList?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, arraylist, iterator

I am trying to convert a Java project into a C++ project. In the Java project, I used an ArrayList, but I don't know the best way of handling what I did in C++.

Currently I am using a std::vector because it allows access of elements at arbitrary positions, and because it has an insert method. Like a Java ArrayList, I want to be able to insert an element at a certain position (int p) in the vector and have the element currently at p (if any) shifted to p+1. And subsequent elements would be shifted as well.

std::vector.insert for a single entry looks like this:

```
iterator insert (iterator position, const value_type& val);
```

and the description from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/ says

> Because vectors use an array as their underlying storage, inserting elements in
>       positions other than the vector end causes the container to relocate all
>       the elements that were after position to their new positions.

Does this mean that insert actually puts the new element at p+1 and NOT p? Does it not shift the element currently at p as well?

Also, why does the insert method take in an iterator instead of just a number index? I don't see the advantage. It just makes it more difficult to insert at arbitrary positions. Is there some way to construct an iterator to be at a specific location without having to iterate there? I only see comparisons at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/

Comment: ArrayList works like a vector in that it "uses an array as the underlying storage" and "relocate" does indeed mean "move". From the same link: "The vector is extended by inserting new elements *before* the element at the specified position, *effectively increasing the container size by the number of elements inserted.*"

Comment: DOes it reallocate the element at the position where a new element is being inserted? Or does it keep it where it is and just put the new element right after it?

Comment: "The vector is extended by inserting new elements *before* the element at the specified position, effectively increasing the container size by the number of elements inserted."

Comment: @pst Thanks I missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector does exactly what you need, but the boundary condition is a bit different.

The iterator you give it points to the element you want to insert *before*.

In other wirds, if you pass it an iterator pointing to the first element, then it will insert the new element *at the start of the vector*, and push the element that *was* the first to the second position.

> Also, why does the insert method take in an iterator instead of just a number index? I don't see the advantage. It just makes it more difficult to insert at arbitrary positions. Is there some way to construct an iterator to be at a specific location without having to iterate there?

Why is it more difficult?

To get an iterator pointing to the 17th element, do this:

```
vec.begin() + 17;
```

I don't know what you mean by "having to iterate there", but you don't need to increment the iterator 17 times.

Comment: Thanks, It's been a long day of  C++ when I'd rather just work with Java. Thanks for explaining it, the iterator is easier to use than I thought. Again, thanks so much.

Comment: @AABoucher As for *why* it uses iterators instead of indices, the short answer is that iterators enable a simple, uniform and very flexible interface for expressing all sorts of algorithms across all container types. If you want a more detailed explanation, you should ask that as a separate question. :)